# Flutter. How can i simulate a click on a widget without a GestureDetector?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, touch, flutter-test, gesturedetector

Did someone face such a task? if so, I would be glad to see examples of how you can emulate a click on a widget without a GestureDetector?

Comment: Hi, could you explain why you don't want to use a `GestureDetector` so it's easier to understand your usecase?

Comment: in my case, a widget is made in the form of a drop-down list from the bottomModalsheet, and when I want to switch focus from the textfield to the drop-down list, I need to emulate a click

Comment: To be sure, you want to open the drop-down list? What triggers this?
If you could include relevant code, that will help understand this.